# 'range' cannot be used as a variable or function name

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator, pine-script-v4

the error is:

> Compilation error. Line 13: 'range' cannot be used as a variable or
> function name.

```
//@version=5
indicator('My Script')



// 计算振幅
range = high - low


// 定义信息框显示的内容
info = "开盘价: " + tostring(open) + "\n"
        + "最高价: " + tostring(high) + "\n"
        + "最低价: " + tostring(low) + "\n"
        + "振幅: " + tostring(range) + "\n"
        + "成交量: " + tostring(volume)

// 定义当鼠标悬停在当前k线时显示信息框
bgcolor(not nz(bgcolor[1]) and barstate.ishovered, color.new(color.red, 50))

// 当鼠标悬停在当前k线时，显示信息框
label.new(bar_index, high, text=info, xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.abovebar
```

Comment: this  cant work,  the range really dont know why,  there // 计算振幅
range = high - low, the range has ﹏this red one below and says   'range' cannot be used as a variable or function name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of error.
For the range problem, just change :

```
range = high - low
```

To :

```
myrange = high - low
```

Comment: sir, i dont get, i am just beginner,after i change it as myrange =high - low, there are more problems  Line 12: Mismatched input '+' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: @foxDes If my answer solved your question, please accept it and ask a new one (questions are forbiden in comments)

Comment: no sir, it didnt

Comment: after i change as your answer

Comment: there are more problems ,  Line 12: Mismatched input '+' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: You asked for the line 13. Please open a new question

Comment: sorry,i dont know rules here

Comment: @foxDes the rules in Stackoverflow are one question only each time. No question in comment. If the answer help on your question you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

// Supply Zone
supply = high == highest(high, 20)
supplyzone = plot(supply ? high : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, title="Supply Zone")
fill(hline(price=high, title="Supply Fill Zone"), supply ? low : na, color=fillzonecolor, title="Supply Fill Zone", opacity=zoneopacity)
Compilation error:  1-Cannot call 'hline' with 'price'=series[float]. The argument should be of type: input float
2-Cannot call 'hline' with 'price'=series[float]. The argument should be of type: input float

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).